# Conditional "Where" clause and custom function

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012, I have a big query that have this where clause:

```
(1 = Case 
    When (@bSomeSpecialCheck = 'Y') Then 
        Case When (dbo.SomeFunction(SomeColumn, @SomeParam)=1) Then 1 Else 0 End
Else 1 End)
```

I know that "SomeFunction" is a slow one, and I want that to be evaluated only if there is a value in @SomeParam. So I wrote the where this way, because I want to avoid the execution of "SomeFunction" if not needed.

Well, the thing is that regardless @bSomeSpecialCheck is always "N", it seems that SQL Server is evaluating the whole Case, because if I write it this way for testing purposes:

```
(1 = Case 
    When (@bSomeSpecialCheck = 'Y') Then 
        Case When (1=1) Then 1 Else 0 End
Else 1 End)
```

I get an immediate response, so I know that my slow function "SomeFunction" is being evaluated, but why?
How can I avoid the evaluation of SomeFunction only when @bSomeSpecialCheck is "Y"?

Comment: You could add @bSomeSpecialCheck as Parameter to dbo.SomeFunction and decide inside what to return, with or without calculations...

Comment: The only call to "SomeFunction" is already causing slowness since there are about 200,000 records to be evaluated, I tried by making the function dummy and return true immediately, and it is as slow as with the calculations inside enabled.

Comment: Your original expression can be factored down. The following is functionally equivalent and much shorter/simpler: `1 = CASE WHEN @bSomeSpecialCheck = 'Y' THEN dbo.SomeFunction(SomeColumn, @SomeParam) ELSE 1 END`

Comment: What about `@bSomeSpecialCheck = 'N' OR dbo.SomeFunction(SomeColumn, @SomeParam)=1`. Maybe SQL Server will evaluate this as written?! Anyway, evaluation order is mosty not guaranteed. It *should* be guaranteed as part of a CASE but that is buggy as hell.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That shorter/simpler cause the same behavior: the "SomeFunction" function is being evaluated regardless bSomeSpecialCheck = 'N'. I did the double, nested case, in an attempt to avoid the query to evaluate the other function.

Comment: @usr I tried that and the query takes its time to finish even when bSomeSpecialCheck = 'N', again SQL Server is calling "SomeFunction", eventhough it does not affect the result, i.e. the final result is like if it was respected (and it was), but the execution time tells me SQL did the call to SomeFunction even when it didn't had to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only way to avoid this is to duplicate your query

```
if (@bSomeSpecialCheck = 'Y') Then
begin
   Whole Query with function
end
else
begin
  Whole Query without function
end
```

Comment: This is actually a sure way to do it.